# SKProductsRequest message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i went trough a lot of similar questions, tried everything, but couldn't get it to work. Can anybody help me with that?

My Code:

```
    @implementation DSInAppSubscriptionManager

- (void)requestProUpgradeProductData
{
    NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:@"productID"];
    self.productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
    self.productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [self.productsRequest start];
}


- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response{
    NSArray *products = response.products;
    proUpgradeProduct = [products count] == 1 ? [products firstObject] : nil;
    if (proUpgradeProduct)
    {
        NSLog(@"Product title: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedTitle);
        NSLog(@"Product description: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedDescription);
        NSLog(@"Product price: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.price);
        NSLog(@"Product id: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.productIdentifier);
    }

    for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
    {
        NSLog(@"Invalid product id: %@" , invalidProductId);
    }

}

-(void)requestDidFinish:(SKRequest *)request{
    NSLog(@"finished");
}
-(void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"fail");
}

//-(void)dealloc{
//    self.productsRequest.delegate = nil;
//    [self.productsRequest cancel];
//    self.productsRequest = nil;
//}

@end
```

Now... with the dealloc commented it gives me that message :
*** -[DSInAppSubscriptionManager retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x18742450

If i uncomment the dealloc method, it doesn't show that message, but don't call any of the delegates.

I'm calling the method requestProUpgradeProductData from a ViewController.

Comment: It seems like your DSInAppSubscriptionManager is being deallocated before the request completes. When do you deallocate it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer... i was instantiating this class (DSInAppSubscriptionManager) as a weak object in my viewController... so when it called the delegate it was already deallocated... My mistake...